# Check In\Out Issue on updating XSLTLISTVIEWWEBPART list view from code behind in sharepoint

Tags: listview, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, .net-3.5, sharepoint-list

I am trying to change the current list view using CAML query and then updating the current view  .This functionality works fine on pages which does not have check in\out disabled.But I am getting following error message on check in\out enabled pages.

Message : "**The file is not checked out. You must first check out this document before making changes"**.

I am getting above error message at currentview.update() line......
[image: Code behind:]

Answer (score 1):

Probably: The view is on a page. You need to checkout that page before updating the view.

However, I got this error on de WebPartManager.SaveChanges(). Because that saves the changes to the page, where the webparts is placed on.